# Esiste una parola per "schioccare la lingua"?

Tags: vocabulary

Osservo che in Italia, in contesti informali, talvolta si usa un breve schiocco della lingua in luogo di "No", tipicamente in risposta a una domanda del tipo sì/no.
Esiste una parola che indichi appropriatamente l'azione di schioccare la lingua in segno di diniego?

Comment: ...uhm... l'unico "schiocco" che mi venga in mente è sempre (almeno) doppio e sul palato. È quello che intendi?

Comment: Non penso esista un termine specifico per 'far schioccare la lingua'. In inglese si dice 'to chirrup' ma si riferisce nello specifico  a quando si va a cavallo (per richiamare l'attenzione).

Comment: @Bakuriu, esiste anche lo schiocco singolo per dire "no", di sicuro in Lazio e in Sicilia (le regioni che conosco meglio). In Sicilia è spesso accompagnato da una leggera rotazione indietro della testa, mentre nel Lazio è talvolta accompagnato da un leggero scuotimento della testa.

Comment: @WalterTross Non in Friuli.

Comment: Esatto: mi riferivo esattamente al singolo schiocco che riporta @WalterTross, che ho osservato in persone siciliane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si chiama [**consonante clic**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/clic/) o, come hai visto, 'click'

In termini tecnici 'fonetici' si definisce una *consonante non polmonare centrale dentale (o anche alveolare)* e si indica con un punto esclamativo **/ ! /**

In italiano comune non si può definire schiocco: con questo termine si indica il rumore o di un *bacio* (tramite aspirazione: '*smack*') o di una frusta o della sua imitazione con la lingua per incitare un cavallo, in questo caso è un 'clic laterale'

Se conosci l'inglese questo suono, che ripetuto indica disapprovazione anche in italiano, si trascrive '*tut-tut*' in BE and 'tsk-tsk' in AE.

Answer (score 1):

Si può dire certamente anche schiocco. Il Garzanti porta:

«agitare, muovere, sfregare in modo da produrre uno schiocco: schioccare le dita; **schioccare la lingua, appoggiarla al palato e staccarla di scatto così da produrre un rumore secco;** schioccare un bacio, dare un bacio producendo uno schiocco»

vedi http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=schioccare

Però sarebbe buono conoscere un termine "tecnico", con cui magari si descrive il fenomeno da secoli. Chissà se l'origine è un'antica lingua o la fantasia popolare...